# Show that PDE solution is symmetrical

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I got the following PDE
$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{d^2}{dy^2}f(x,y)+\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}(x\cdot f(x,y)))$$
The boundary conditions are
$$f(x,0)=f(x,1)=f(a,y)=f(b,y)=0.$$

The task is to show using
$$f(x,y)=\sum_n a_n(x)\sin(n\pi y) $$
that $a_n=0$ for $n$ even and for $n$ odd
$$a_n=-\frac{1}{x}\frac{2}{n\pi}-\frac{n^2\pi^2}{2}a_n+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}(x\cdot f(x,y))).$$
From numerical analysis I know that $f(x,\frac{1+y}{2})=f(x,\frac{1-y}{2})$ but I have no clue how to show this analytically. Showing this makes it easy to show that all $a_n$ even go to zero. Nevertheless this would not explain the odd coefficients.

I would really appreciate your help!

Best,
Alex

Comment: I solved it by multiplying $sin(m\pi z$ on both sides in by integrating $z$ from $0$ to $1$. I end up with two expressions for either n even or n odd. Using a power series solution ansatz it can be shown that all of its coefficients for n even go to zero.